# Convert Pythonic approach of looping into nested loops

Tags: python, python-2.7, loops, nested-loops, python-2.x

I am a beginner in Python. I'd like to understand the Pythonic approach of looping as I am a C coder for a long time. Given the following two lines:

```
{k: v for out_d in outs for k, v in out_d.iteritems()}
[{} for i in range(nthreads)]
```

Can someone break it down so that it follows the C standard approach of nested loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {k: v for out_d in outs for k, v in out_d.iteritems()}

# is equivalent to

my_dict = {}
for out_d in outs:
    for key, value in out_d.iteritems():
        my_dict[key] = value



my_list = [{} for i in range(nthreads)]

# is equivalent to

my_list = []
for i in range(nthreads):
    my_list.append({})
```

Answer (score 1):

The equivalents are:

```
res = {}
for out_d in outs:
    for k, v in out_d.iteritems():
        res[k] = v

res = []
for i in range(nthreads):
    res.append({})
```

Note that you can find these relatively simply yourself by using different indentation:

```
{k: v for out_d in outs for k, v in out_d.iteritems()}

=>

{k: v 
 for out_d in outs 
 for k, v in out_d.iteritems()}

=>

{        k: v 
 for out_d in outs 
     for k, v in out_d.iteritems()}
```

The only tricky bit is that the first statement `k: v` is actually in the inner-most loop but all the later expressions are ordered in the order of the "loopy"-equivalent. Also the first statement will be different depending on the type of comprehension.

For dict-comprehensions it's `the_dict[key] = value` instead of `key: value`, for list comprehensions it's `the_list.append(value)` and for set-comprehensions it's `the_set.add(value)`. It's more complicated with generator expressions because you have to write a function that `yield value`.

Answer (score 1):

```
for key, value in out_d.iteritems()
```

-- `iteritems()` loops over the key/value of a dictionary, so `out_d` must be a dictionary

```
for out_d in outs
```

-- `for out_d in outs` will loop over the iterator in `outs`, and based on the previous we can assume this is a list of dictionaries

```
{k:v}
```

-- this creates a new dictionary comprehension using the values of k, v

All together:

Create a dictionary comprehension of the values k, v for each key, value in the dictionary out_d, for each out_d in the list outs

```
new_dict = {}
for dictionary in outs:
    for key, value in dictionary.iteritems()
        new_dict[key] = value
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python: List Comprehensions

Python supports a concept called "list comprehensions". It can be used to construct lists in a very natural, easy way, like a mathematician is used to do.

The following are common ways to describe lists (or sets, or tuples, or vectors) in mathematics.

```
S = {x² : x in {0 ... 9}}
V = (1, 2, 4, 8, ..., 2¹²)
M = {x | x in S and x even}
```

You probably know things like the above from mathematics lessons at school. In Python, you can write these expression almost exactly like a mathematician would do, without having to remember any special cryptic syntax.

This is how you do the above in Python:

```
>>> S = [x**2 for x in range(10)]
>>> V = [2**i for i in range(13)]
>>> M = [x for x in S if x % 2 == 0]
>>> 
>>> print S; print V; print M
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
[1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256, 512, 1024, 2048, 4096]
[0, 4, 16, 36, 64]
```

I'm sure you want to see a more complicated example. :-) The following is yet another way to compute prime numbers. The interesting thing is that we first build a list of non-prime numbers, using a single list comprehension, then use another list comprehension to get the "inverse" of the list, which are prime numbers.

```
>>> noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
>>> primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
>>> print primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

NB: You can nest list comprehensions inside of each other, so you could write the above example with a single statement (without the need for the temporary variable "noprimes"). However, such lines tend to get long and less readable, so this is not recommended.

Of course, list comprehensions don't only work for numbers. Lists can contain any type of elements, including strings, nested lists and functions. You can even mix different types within a list.

The following works on a list of strings and produces a list of lists. Each of the sublists contains two strings and an integer.

```
>>> words = 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'.split()
>>> print words
['The', 'quick', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumps', 'over', 'the', 'lazy', 'dog']
>>> 
>>> stuff = [[w.upper(), w.lower(), len(w)] for w in words]
>>> for i in stuff:
...     print i
... 
['THE', 'the', 3]
['QUICK', 'quick', 5]
['BROWN', 'brown', 5]
['FOX', 'fox', 3]
['JUMPS', 'jumps', 5]
['OVER', 'over', 4]
['THE', 'the', 3]
['LAZY', 'lazy', 4]
['DOG', 'dog', 3]
>>> 
>>> stuff = map(lambda w: [w.upper(), w.lower(), len(w)], words)
>>> for i in stuff:
...     print i
... 
['THE', 'the', 3]
['QUICK', 'quick', 5]
['BROWN', 'brown', 5]
['FOX', 'fox', 3]
['JUMPS', 'jumps', 5]
['OVER', 'over', 4]
['THE', 'the', 3]
['LAZY', 'lazy', 4]
['DOG', 'dog', 3]
```

The above example also demonstrates that you can do exactly the same thing with map() and a lambda function. However, there are cases when you cannot use map() and have to use a list comprehension instead, or vice versa. When you can use both, then it is often preferable to use a list comprehension, because this is more efficient and easier to read, most of the time.

You cannot use list comprehensions when the construction rule is too complicated to be expressed with "for" and "if" statements, or if the construction rule can change dynamically at runtime. In this case, you better use map() and / or filter() with an appropriate function. Of course, you can combine that with list comprehensions.